# SAP Business One Query - Beginner SQL - SUM of column for unique dates

Tags: sql, variables, sapb1

Morning, all. Beginner here in terms of SQL, but I've done other programming languages and system management. I am teaching myself SQL but am probably in the beginner stage, working on writing some reports to more efficiently dump data for analysis.

I have the following query written but am having issues with a column. Building the report in this way sums the `F.Quantity` column undesirably. The `FCT1` database is just item no for rows and dates for columns with quantity in the cells. This report sums goods receipt data for each unique item no. The `FCT1` DB is tied in on `ItemNo` and bound by date, however, using SUM here SUMs the Quantity data in `FCT1` for each goods receipt.

I want to attach the SUM per item number of total quantities in `FCT1` within the specified date range without duplicating the data for each individual goods receipt.

DISTINCT will not work as duplicate values exist in the `FCT1.Quantity` fields and should not be omitted. I know I could probably write a loop, but I've been trying to learn this correctly and I'm sure there's a very simple solution.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried different parameters for joining the DBs but believe I need to declare a variable or some such. I haven't gotten there yet.

Code:

```
SELECT
B.ItemCode,
B.Dscription,
SUM(B.Quantity) as 'Cases',
SUM(B.Quantity) * C.U_CONVERSIONFACTOR as 'Finished LB',
AVG(B.INMPrice) as 'Average Cost',
SUM(B.Quantity) * AVG(B.INMPrice) as 'Total Cost',
E.Price as 'Average Sales Price',
E.Price * SUM(B.Quantity) as 'Total Revenue',
SUM(F.Quantity) as 'Scheduled'

FROM
OIGN A
LEFT JOIN IGN1 B ON A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN [@BMM_UNITCONVERSION] C ON C.U_ITEMCODE = B.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN OITM D ON D.ItemCode = B.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN ITM1 E ON E.ItemCode = D.ItemCode
RIGHT JOIN FCT1 F ON F.ItemCode = B.ItemCode AND F.AbsID = 4

WHERE
B.DocDate >= [%0] AND B.DocDate <= [%1]
AND LEFT(B.ItemCode, 2) = 30
AND B.WhsCode = 'IZBA'
AND C.U_TOUNIT = 'LB'
AND E.PriceList = 11
AND F.Date >= [%0] AND F.Date <= [%1]

GROUP BY
B.ItemCode,
B.Dscription,
C.U_CONVERSIONFACTOR,
E.Price
```

Comment: Hi - please update your question with a minimal reproducible example: from what I can see only tables B and F are actually relevant to your question. Provide table definitions, sample data, the result you want to achieve and the SQL you’ve managed to write so far. On a more general note, I’m not sure why you are using table A at all in your SQL as it doesn’t seem to appear in either your SELECT or WHERE clauses - so it is having no impact on your SQL